DataGridTemplateColumn with ComboBox not populating with initial value from DataGrid source when ComboBox source is class instead of enum
I have an Avalonia MVVM project using CommunityToolkit. Below is a paired down version of what my code looks like. The ComboBox column with the enum works as expected, when the DataGrid loads the ComboBox populates with the correct option, and when I change it the source changes. The ComboBox column with the object source however, does not work correctly. When the DataGrid loads the ComboBox doesn't automatically populate with the correct option (although the dropdown is full). When I select a different option from the ComboBox, it stays populated, and the source updates as well.
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ComboOptionId { get; set; }
    public ComboEnum ComboOption 
    {
        get => (ComboEnum)ComboOptionId;

        set => ComboOptionId = (int)value;
    }

    public ComboObject ComboObject { get; set; }
} 

public class ComboObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public enum ComboEnum
{
    Option1 = -1,
    Option2 = 0,
    Option3 = 1
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ComboEnum> ComboEnumOptions { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<ComboObject> ComboObjectOptions { get; }

    public ObersvableCollection<MyObject> ObjectSource { get; }

    // Rest of class has methods to fill these and other operations etc...
}

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectSource}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ComboEnum">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding
                      Path=((vm:ViewModel)DataContext).ComboEnumOptions,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding ComboOption}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ComboObject">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding 
                      Path=((vm:ViewModel)DataContext).ComboObjectOptions, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding ComboObject}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>


I'm wondering if its an issue of the ComboObject not being the same reference as the ComboObject in the ObservableCollection but I'm not sure how to go about resolving that if it is.
